# Strange behaviour while setting up Flink metrics reporting with InfluxDB

Tags: java, apache-flink, influxdb, flink-streaming

While attempting to execute a Flink job on a Flink cluster (1.9) in kubernetes and having the metrics recorded in an influxdb time series database, a "series" of very strange events have occurred.

Lets say we have this extremely simple job:

```
// setup Kafka consumer
Properties kafkaConsumerProps = new Properties();
kafkaConsumerProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", ...);
kafkaConsumerProps.setProperty("group.id", ...);

FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> myConsumer =
      new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), kafkaConsumerProps);

StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L);

// create direct kafka stream
DataStream<String> trafficEventStream = env.addSource(myConsumer);

trafficEventStream.map(new RichMapFunction<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String map(String value) throws Exception {
          return value;
    }
});

env.execute("Traffic");
```

NOTE: the job doesn't really matter, it has been stripped down to the bare bones.

Configuration of the cluster has been set in `flink-conf.yaml` as per the documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html):

```
metrics.reporter.influxdb.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporter
metrics.reporter.influxdb.host: influxdb
metrics.reporter.influxdb.port: 8086
metrics.reporter.influxdb.db: flink
metrics.reporter.influxdb.username: flink-metrics
metrics.reporter.influxdb.password: qwerty
```

However when the job is submitted to the cluster, the logs are polluted with the following error messages:

```
2020-02-05 21:45:13,135 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl Error while reporting metrics 
 org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.shaded.org.influxdb.InfluxDBException\$UnableToParseException:partial write: unable to parse 'taskmanager_job_task_operator_reauthentication-latency-avg,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic,operator_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,operator_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=8fda43cec7b39138c4a5cc6f8738971f,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a value=� 1580939113059000000': invalid boolean
unable to parse 'taskmanager_job_task_operator_KafkaConsumer_sync-time-avg,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic,operator_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,operator_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=8fda43cec7b39138c4a5cc6f8738971f,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a value=� 1580939113059000000': invalid boolean
unable to parse 'taskmanager_job_task_operator_commit-latency-avg,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic,operator_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,operator_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=8fda43cec7b39138c4a5cc6f8738971f,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a value=� 1580939113059000000': invalid boolean
unable to parse 'taskmanager_job_task_operator_commit-latency-max,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic,operator_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,operator_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=8fda43cec7b39138c4a5cc6f8738971f,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a value=� 1580939113059000000': invalid boolean
```

this goes on for quite a while and then:

```
    at org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.shaded.org.influxdb.InfluxDBException.buildExceptionFromErrorMessage(InfluxDBException.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.shaded.org.influxdb.InfluxDBException.buildExceptionForErrorState(InfluxDBException.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.shaded.org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.execute(InfluxDBImpl.java:796)
    at org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.shaded.org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.write(InfluxDBImpl.java:455)
    at org.apache.flink.metrics.influxdb.InfluxdbReporter.report(InfluxdbReporter.java:101)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl$ReporterTask.run(MetricRegistryImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Taking a look into influxdb, when the `show series` command line argument is executed in the CLI on the `flink` database, the following extremely strange series names are listed:

```
jobmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Time,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesLoaded,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesUnloaded,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_Copy_Count,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_Copy_Time,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_MarkSweepCompact_Count,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_MarkSweepCompact_Time,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_Count,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_MemoryUsed,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_TotalCapacity,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Committed,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Max,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_Count,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_MemoryUsed,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_TotalCapacity,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Committed,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Max,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Used,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_Status_JVM_Threads_Count,host=flink-jobmanager
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=078a136e99f5028671744fe4da4ef814,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=2b4aa6d82aea381721d435fa36f56afc,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=613e99628c06c38211fb63d31afe8f0f,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=d4ead0ce5e17397c03969a6c89790f54,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_downtime,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=e977b10e9ed0f236bb154515c708682b,job_name=Traffic
jobmanager_job_fullRestarts,host=flink-jobmanager,job_id=078a136e99f5028671744fe4da4ef814,job_name=Traffic
```

and it gets weirder the further south we go:

```
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBuffersInRemotePerSecond,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=d4ead0ce5e17397c03969a6c89790f54,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=ef8aae2b44854021f18aeb4707babd06,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBuffersInRemotePerSecond,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=e977b10e9ed0f236bb154515c708682b,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=2c96da26392011d06220871513bd5f8b,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBytesInLocal,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-kzq2h,job_id=2b4aa6d82aea381721d435fa36f56afc,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=886a48ce0db510645a48a5541038fe89,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=7e175a73b9a3ae1c3a8d748982530aa2
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBytesInLocal,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-kzq2h,job_id=e977b10e9ed0f236bb154515c708682b,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=fc071b097d73d8ed9a1688a3d8251cf4,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=7e175a73b9a3ae1c3a8d748982530aa2
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBytesInLocal,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=078a136e99f5028671744fe4da4ef814,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=e791473d96872ce886a60aa547f139e4,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a
taskmanager_job_task_Shuffle_Netty_Output_numBytesInLocal,host=flink-taskmanager-6484bdf6c5-ssmdc,job_id=45fd8a6e0dbae699a4fd810d5fecc65f,job_name=Traffic,subtask_index=0,task_attempt_id=8fda43cec7b39138c4a5cc6f8738971f,task_attempt_num=0,task_id=cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2,task_name=Source:\ Custom\ Source\ ->\ Map,tm_id=12f6e13572c00ec73a98734e4c5d307a
```

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: Could you please add what's so strange about the metric names? I'm not getting it.

Comment: The number of InfluxDB time `series` was increasing in number continuously the longer the job executed, not the values contained within each series. Was advised that it might be related to the fact that prior to 1.10 the influx connector did not filter out certain values. Switched to Prometheus and no problems at all.